# Problem with ap-hotspot

Tags: 14.04, process, hot-spot

This is the message displayed in my terminal screen when I typed

```
sudo ap-hotspot start

Another process is already running
```

Which process is running and how do I stop it?

Comment: sudo ap-hotspot stop

Comment: @Sudheer algosig@algosig:~$ **sudo ap-hotspot stop**
[sudo] password for algosig: 
**Wireless Hotspot is not active**
algosig@algosig:~$ **sudo ap-hotspot start**
**Another process is already running**
_HERE IS THE TROUBLE_

Comment: possible duplicate of [ap-hotspot error "Another process is already runnung"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/525685/ap-hotspot-error-another-process-is-already-runnung)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found this solution

```
sudo rm /tmp/hotspot.pid
```

this will delete the process id created temporarily  and no more the error is displayed. This worked in my case.

Answer (score 2):

The problem may be with the **recent version hostapd package** that installs with ap-hotspot.

First uninstall ap-hotspot.
Download old hostapd package(bug free) you can get it from

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa/hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
```

To install hostpad.deb you can use gdebi package manager or simply

```
sudo dpkg -i hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
```

After installation hold the package so no latest versions gets updated

```
   sudo apt-mark hold hostapd
```

Now install ap-hotspot normally.

- Do not update the hostapd package.

Comment: Do we install ap-hotspot again? I did so sudo apt-get install  and again configured and started ap-hotspot but again  error was displayed " Another process already running...                             ps -ef | grep ap-hotspot   this displayed                                                            algosig  19117 17645  0 23:14 pts/8    00:00:00 grep --color=auto ap-hotspot