# ap-hotspot error "Another process is already running"

Tags: process, hot-spot

ap-hotspot is configured, when i first entered the ***command sudo ap-hotspot*** it said starting wireless hotspot  which took long time but didn't start. Afterwards it displays following errors:

[image]

Comment: Seems like a bug. You have a similar issue here http://askubuntu.com/questions/506103/problem-with-ap-hotspot.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem from Internet. By removing the pid file in `/tmp` I got rid of this error "**Another process is already running**"

```
sudo rm /tmp/hotspot.pid
```

then start `ap-hotspot` as,

```
sudo ap-hotspot start
```